# Webpage loads before websql

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want my index page (in Phonegap) to check if there is a user with id >= 1 and then forward to the login page. I think the page loads before the database is ready and therefore the re-direct doesn't work. How do I get this to work?

```
function renderTodo(row) { 
pass = row.todo; 
ID = row.ID 

if (ID >= 1) { 

window.location.href = "login.html"; 

} 
else { 
window.location.href = "#page1"; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the value of ID from the SQLResultSet in the following way and perform actions based on the results.

```
function queryDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(results.rows.item(i).id >= 1) {
           window.location.href = "login.html"; 
        } 
        else { 
           window.location.href = "#page1"; 
        }
    }
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
```